# How to use shortest_rout command of OSMX?

Tags: julia

how to run the Shortest path for a mapdata?
shortest_route(m::MapData, node1::Int, node2::Int; routing::Symbol = :astar)

what do we need to substitud as  routing and symbol??

Is there any possiblity to have k shoretest path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the parameter `routing` can have one of two values: either `:astar` or `:dijkstra` and the appropriate algorithm will be use respectively.

Currently in order to get k-shortest route you would need to use Graphs.jl. The distances are stored in the `w` field hence you could do (assuming you want to have 3 shortest paths between nodes 2341328633 and 52831601 and `m` is an object of `MapData` type):

```
Graphs.yen_k_shortest_paths(m.g, m.v[2341328633], m.v[52831601], m.w,3)
```

The field `v` stores information about mapping OSM nodes to vertices of `SimpleDiGraph` stored in the field `g` within a `MapData` object, and `w` is a sparse matrix with distances.